# Why do I need getInputStream for HttpUrlConnection to send request?

Tags: java, post, applet, request, httpurlconnection

I have some code that sends a POST request to a PHP script from a Java applet:

```
String message = URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8");
URL url = new URL(getCodeBase(), "script.php");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
out.write("message=" + message);
out.close();
```

But this doesn't work in sending the request.  I have to add code that calls getInputStream() and reads all of the input for this to work.  Why is this?  What do I do if I only want to only send a request and not receive one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't, but you do have to call either `getInputStream()` or `getResponseCode()`. Otherwise nothing is sent, but also otherwise you don't have any way of knowing whether the call succeeded or not.